# using of GROUP BY in mysql 8

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-8.0

I have upgraded my MySQL server and now I have a problem with group by

```
select * from tickets WHERE `status` = 0 group by `tnumber` ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
```

error is:

> SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Updated:
my table content is:

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <style>
        table {
          font-family: arial, sans-serif;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          width: 100%;
        }

        td, th {
          border: 1px solid #dddddd;
          text-align: left;
          padding: 8px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
          background-color: #dddddd;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>

        <h2>id</h2>

        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>tnumber</th>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>status</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>5c63e00a072c1</td>
            <td>1111</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>5c63e00a072c1</td>
            <td>1111</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>5c63e00a072c1</td>
            <td>1111</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5c63e00a072c1</td>
            <td>1111</td>
            <td>0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>5c63ead5bd530</td>
            <td>2222</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>5c63ead5bd530</td>
            <td>2222</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <br/>
        I want to have following output:
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>tnumber</th>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>status</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>5c63e00a072c1</td>
            <td>1111</td>
            <td>0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>5c63ead5bd530</td>
            <td>222</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>
```

My code is :

```
SELECT * FROM tickets 
WHERE `tnumber` IN ( 
                      SELECT tnumber FROM tickets GROUP BY tnumber
                   )
```

but group by in second Select in where, doesn't have any affecs!!!
How to do it in a propper way?

The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the result-set by one or more columns.

Comment: you can only select columns which are in group by clause (`tnumber`) or aggregartion functions

Comment: this is not the problem of updating mysql. the problem is the query. this link will help you more about GROUP BY https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: @El.Ham That is not correct. In oder mysql versions it is possible to select columns outside of group by clause

Comment: @Jens - This is a wrong duplicate reference. The WHERE clause is just fine here.

Comment: Updated my code @Jens  please take a look, I want to select best answer

Comment: SELECT * from tickets where id in (SELECT max(id) FROM `tickets` GROUP BY `tnumber`) AND usrid = 1107089

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code from:

```
select * from tickets WHERE `status` = 0 group by `tnumber`;
```

To:

```
SELECT * from tickets where id in (SELECT max(id) FROM tickets GROUP BY tnumber) AND `status` = 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on your question, it looks like that the query was working properly prior to `MySql` upgrade. Since you've upgraded `MySql`, default settings has been applied which means `Only_Full_Group_By` is enabled. Hence, if you want to execute queries like the one in question where non-aggregated columns in `Select` list are not in `group by` clause, you need to disable `Only_Full_Group_By`.

Run below statement & execute your query again:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Warning: You should only do this if you're sure that other non-aggreegated columns in select list are unique for each `tnumber` otherwise you'll get random rows as a result.

Following is quoted from MYSQL 8.0 Manual:

> MySQL implements detection of functional dependence. If the
>   ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL
>   rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER
>   BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the
>   GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them.
>
> If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard
>   SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or
>   ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns
>   are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL
>   to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to
>   choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the
>   values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you
>   want. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be
>   influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Result set sorting occurs
>   after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which
>   value within each group the server chooses. Disabling
>   ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is useful primarily when you know that, due to some
>   property of the data, all values in each nonaggregated column not
>   named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group.

FOR More info, [Click Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).

Comment: What do you mean by Group by doesn't have any effect? And based on what condition you want that output? Also, you had 2 queries in your question. Which query you're actually using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are grouping by a column, the result will be aggregated row(s). As the error message says, it can't display non-aggregated rows with aggregated column. You can restructure your query like this:

```
SELECT `tnumber`
from tickets 
WHERE `status` = 0 
group by `tnumber` 
ORDER BY `tnumber` DESC
```

**Update**

If you want to fetch the record with MAX `id` then you can do the following:

```
SELECT `usrid` , `tnumber` , `title` , `message` , `status` , `created_at` , `type` 
FROM tickets 
WHERE status = 0
AND `id` IN (
    SELECT MAX(`id`)
    FROM tickets
);
```

Comment: Can i use two select? can u help me?

Comment: @MohammadAlipour yes, you can. What do you want in the output?

Comment: In first Select I want tnumbers with max id ,,, and then select * other colums of first select

Comment: select DISTINCT(`tnumber`) , `title` , `message` , `status` , `created_at` , `type` from tickets WHERE `status` = 0    not work

Comment: @MohammadAlipour added another query.

Comment: I need something like this : SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE tnumber IN (SELECT tnumber FROM tickets WHERE status = 0 Group by tnumber)   But group by does not have effects ,, there is non unique tnumber in output

Comment: max id is not tnumber, I have an id column,  I need unique tnumbers with max id, select * from tickets WHERE `status` = 0 group by `tnumber`

Comment: Changed the query again.

Comment: thanks for your help, BUT I dont need only one tnumber with max id,  I want unique tnumbers with max id, look carefully ,   SELECT *` FROM tickets WHERE status = 0 AND `tnumber` IN ( SELECT  tnumber FROM tickets where id is max group by tnumber )

Comment: Could you add the input data and expected output in the question?

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear. So, you want to list only one `tnumber` with max id? As far as I can see in the example, `id` is always incremental.

Comment: id is always incremental, but tnumber is not unique , I want only tnumbers that has max id ,,,,  Group by not work....  I need all tnumbers without repeated

Comment: In which case, the above query (second one in my answer) should work. It returns `tnumber` (and other fields) for max `id`. However, you can change it to return only `tnumber`.